# How to have class-transform converting properly the _id of a mongoDb class?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, class-transformer

I've the following mongoDb class:

```
@Schema()
export class Poker {
  @Transform(({ value }) => value.toString())
  _id: ObjectId;

  @Prop()
  title: string;

  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: User.name })
  @Type(() => User)
  author: User;
}
```

which I return, transformed by `class-transform` in a NestJs server.

It get transformed by an interceptor:

```
  @Get()
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthenticationGuard)
  @UseInterceptors(MongooseClassSerializerInterceptor(Poker))
  async findAll(@Req() req: RequestWithUser) {
    return this.pokersService.findAll(req.user);
  }
```

I'm not the author of the interceptor, but here is how it is implemented:

```
function MongooseClassSerializerInterceptor(
  classToIntercept: Type,
): typeof ClassSerializerInterceptor {
  return class Interceptor extends ClassSerializerInterceptor {
    private changePlainObjectToClass(document: PlainLiteralObject) {
      if (!(document instanceof Document)) {
        return document;
      }

      return plainToClass(classToIntercept, document.toJSON());
    }

    private prepareResponse(
      response: PlainLiteralObject | PlainLiteralObject[],
    ) {
      if (Array.isArray(response)) {
        return response.map(this.changePlainObjectToClass);
      }

      return this.changePlainObjectToClass(response);
    }

    serialize(
      response: PlainLiteralObject | PlainLiteralObject[],
      options: ClassTransformOptions,
    ) {
      return super.serialize(this.prepareResponse(response), options);
    }
  };
}

export default MongooseClassSerializerInterceptor;
```

The problem I'm having, is that when I do a console.log of the return of my controller, I get this:

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("61f030a9527e209d8cad179b"),
    author: {
      _id: new ObjectId("61f03085527e209d8cad1793"),
      password: '--------------------------',
      name: '----------',
      email: '-------------',
      __v: 0
    },
    title: 'Wonderfull first poker2',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

but I get this returned:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "61f5149643092051ba048c6e",
        "author": {
            "_id": "61f5149643092051ba048c6f",
            "name": "----------",
            "email": "-------------",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "title": "Wonderfull first poker2",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

If you check the id, it's not at all the same. Then the client will ask some data for this ID and receive nothing.

Any idea what am I missing?

Also, everytime I make a Get request, I receive a different value back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using this for _id:

```
@Transform(params => params.obj._id)
```

Or this for a more general case:

```
@Transform(({ key, obj }) => obj[key])
```

Stuck with the same problem, solved it this way. params.obj is an original object. Unfortunately, I don't know, why class-transformer doesn't define _id correctly by default.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, I actually ended by doing the same as you: 
  `@Transform((value) => value.obj._id.toString())`

Comment: @FazleRabbiAdor Glad I could pay the favor once ;)

Answer (score 3):

Eventually it is solved by

```
@Transform((value) => value.obj._id.toString())
```

thanks to [J4N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/397830/j4n)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a change to the schema directly and you just use mongoose, you have a schema like below.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    field: String
}, {
    toJSON: {
        transform(doc, ret) {
            ret.id = ret._id;
            delete ret._id;
            delete ret.__v;
        }
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("MySchema", mySchema)
```

But if you are using `@nestjs/mongoose` you should have usage like below.

```
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

export type MyDocument = MyClass & Document;

@Schema({
  toJSON: {
    transform(doc, ret) {
      ret.id = ret._id;
      delete ret._id;
      delete ret.__v;
    },
  },
})
export class MyClass {
  @Prop()
  field: string;
}

export const MySchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(MyClass);
```

Recall that in the first example, the first parameter of the `new mongoose.Schema` function is the schema object and the second parameter is the schema options. So, the class schema object that `@Schema` decarator has, the parameters it will include are Schema options!

Answer (score 0):

after some seach i figure it out,
always treat `ObjectId` as `String` for serializer use `class-transform`
after define `@Type(() => String)` we don't need `@Transform` for
`plain2class` or `class2plain`. also for subdoc in mongoose we need figure out is the field is `populate` for not, if it is return the subdoc type (like below `User`) else just return `String`

`order.schema.ts`

```
...
export class Order {
  // for root _id
  @Type(() => String)
  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId

  // for subdoc _id
  @Prop({ required: true, type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: User.name })
  @Type(({ newObject, object, property }) => {
    // if `createdAt` exists ok it's `populate` 
    if (object[property].createdAt) {
      return User
    } else {
      return String
    }
  })
  user: User
  ...

}
```

`user.schema.ts`

```
export class User {
  @Type(() => String)
  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
}
```

`order.controller.ts`

```
export class OrderController {
  ...
  @Get('item/:id')
  @SerializeOptions({ type: Order })
  @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
  async item(@Param('id') id: string) {
    const item = await this.orderService.getItem(id)
    return item.toJSON()
  }

  @Get('list')
  @SerializeOptions({ type: Order })
  @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
  async list() {
    const item = await this.orderService.getList()
    return item.map((v) => v.toJSON())
  }
  ...
}
```

`order.service.ts`

```
export class OrderService {
  ...

  async getItem(id: string) {
    const query = this.orderModel.findOne()
    // query.populate({
    //   path: 'user'
    // })
    query.where({
      _id: id
    })
    return query.exec()
  }

  async getList() {
    const query = this.orderModel.find()
    // query.populate({
    //   path: 'user'
    // })
    return query.exec()
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer from @OcelotJungle worked for me, but in case anyone prefers a method decorator, and/or no dependency on another library, here is one that worked for me (also changes the _id to id)

```
export default function TransformMongoId() {
    return function (_target: any, _propertyName: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

        descriptor.value = async function (...args: unknown[]) {
            try {
                const result = await originalMethod.apply(this, args);

                const transform = (obj: any) => {
                    if (obj?._id instanceof ObjectId) {
                        obj.id = obj._id.toString();
                        delete obj._id;
                    }
                    return obj;
                };

                if (Array.isArray(result)) {
                    return result.map(transform);
                } else {
                    return transform(result);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                throw error;
            }
        };

        return descriptor;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case with plainToClass this was the solution:

```
  @Expose()
  @Transform(({ value }: {value: string}) => value.toString(), { 
  toPlainOnly: true })
  id: string;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).